# Calling a method within a view in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Let me preface this by saying I am brand new to Laravel and MVC in general. What I am trying to do seems simple but I'm not sure of the proper way to do it inside Laravel. I have a menu/sidebar view that looks like this:

```
@if( Auth::check() )

    <h4>Item Types</h4>
        <ul>
            {{ listUserTypes() }}
        </ul>
@endif
```

What I would like to do is get from MySQL any 'Types' that exists for the current user and loop through them as `<li>`s. I know putting login into the view is definitely the wrong way to do this, but I'm not sure of the correct alternative. Is is proper to put my DB query as a method `listUserTypes()` inside my controller, and if so how would I call that inside a view?

Comment: Put the call to `listUserTypes()` in your controller, and then pass the result of that as a variable to your view using `with()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using MVC pattern the proper way should be define the relations in your models, get the data in your controller and make your view as 'dumb' as possible, that is, the view should only show data w/o knowing where or how the data is retrieved. Using a function in your view means your view is too 'smart'.

```
// =========== models/User.php ===========

public function types()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Type');
}

// =========== controllers/SomeController.php ===========

$user = Auth::user();

return View::make('some.view')->withTypes($user->types);

// =========== some/view.blade.php ===========

<ul>
    @foreach ($types as $type)
    <li>{{ $type->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: What determines that this should go in models/User.php rather than say a Type model?

Comment: The way you said you want to retrieve the data. If you want to retrieve data from an already existing User instance, that means you should define the relation on the model you have the instance of.

What I actually do in real scenarios is always define the relationship in both directions, that is, in both models. Even if you dont need to use the relationship in one of the directions, having both defined helps to understand better your data relations w/o having to take a look to the database schema.

Answer (score 2):

Your views should be "dumb". Whenever you find yourself in the situation where a view requires data, code under the assumption that it already has access to it:

```
@foreach( $userTypes as $userType )
    <li>{{ $userType }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Then in the controller, pass the data to it:

```
return View::make('pages.homepage')
        ->with('userTypes', $userTypes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have this function in your model (a "scope" function retrieving all types for a given user). Then, you call this function in your controller, store result (array) in a variable and pass it to your view. Then, you can use it easily.

**Model/Type entity**

```
public function scopeByUser($query, $user) {
    return $query->...; // Make your query to retrieve types using passed user.
}
```

**Controller**

```
$types = Type::byUser($user)->get();
return View::make('myview', array('types' => $types));
```

**View**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($types as $type)
        <li>{{ $type->label }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Where label is the value you want to display.

Comment: So is it wrong to put my query inside my controller like this? http://laravel.io/bin/GjLPm

Comment: I think it is not how MVC should be used. Model is used for data treatment. Another thing to consider is that if you have to use this query several times in your project, you should have it in your model. If one day "user_id" field becomes "customer_id" or "user", you will be really happy to have to change it only in your model (and you'll know where it is).

Answer (score 0):

I would put the DB query in a method inside your User model.

Then, you will be able to call this method like this:

```
Auth::user()->listUserTypes()
```

If you don't want to call a model directly in your view, an other option is to use the view composer function of Laravel.

http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers

```
View::composer(array('menu.sidebar'), function($view)
{
  $view->with('userTypes', Auth::user()->listUserTypes());
});
```

With this, each time your menu.sidebar view is called, the userTypes variable will be provided.

This way you don't have to send the userTypes variable every time you render a view including *menu.sidebar*.